# How to get PHP Eclipse to align new line with above line

Tags: php, eclipse

Dont know how to search for this. I found some questions similar to this but it doesnt answer/resolve my issue. Basically got a new PC, installed latest version of PHP Eclipse which shows Oxygen version 3.

Basically I have this line of code:

```
        $results = DB::query("
            SELECT
            fld1,
            fld2
            FROM
            table1");
```

As you see the query text aligns beneath one another. So after I type the word SELECT then hit enter, the new line then starts where fld1 is. However under this new PHP Eclipse this happens when I go to a new line:

```
$results = DB::query("
            SELECT 
fld1,
            fld2
            FROM
            table1");
```

I have to hit tab several times to get fld1 to align back up with SELECT above it. Where in PHP Eclipse can I configure the new line to indent properly under the text that is above it. It worked with no changes on the old version of PHP Eclipse, but I cant seem to find the solution in this new version. Can anyone help? This seems to happen for regular text, works just fine while coding in PHP.

Comment: You mean eclipse PDT?  I just deal with the tabbing quirks, the more concerning thing is the lack of autocomplete when in a Closure, which has been an issues sense at least `neon` and continues to be a problem.  And I won't even mention what the composer integration does to the buildpath....  Oh and I broke the scroll wheel on my mouse and half my shift sticker on my laptop (lenovo Y700) is wore off ... :(

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Yes PDT, sorry about that. Yeah I am going to go download an older version then and see if that resolves it. This is affecting my coding too much.

Comment: It is actually incorrect to indent lines like you have, this may have been what previous versions did, but the extra tabs in there actually throw off the format if you were to echo that out.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I couldnt get it to work so I just went back to the Mars build, which works exactly the way I want it to.

Comment: No I tried it and, as it was I was inside of a JavaScript function and not a PHP one... lol.  Sorry about that.  But it formatted it correctly that way for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to resolve this issue with the new Eclipse PDT Oxygen build. I was able to get it resolved by going back to the old version I was using, the Mars build. Couldnt find any other solution currently, though I did see people report something similar as a bug in the new PHP Eclipse PDT, but no resolution itself. But wanted to at least provide what I did to get it to work again.

Comment: This may work but you lose a lot, like the built in composer support, which although it has some minor annoying things is pretty nice.  Also it looks like the closure (anonymous function) autocomplete bug is fixed in Oxygen, where autocomplete does not work in closures.  However I've only been using Oxygen for a few weeks and only at home, if I don't find any major issues I will move to it at work also.